# How do I use gstreamer to listen to AVTP packets and decode H264 data?

Tags: gstreamer, wireshark, video-processing, h.264, video-capture

I am trying to use gstreamer to listen to AVTP packets from an interface and decode H264 data from it.

I have packets coming through an interface eno1, I ran this command0

```
gst-launch-1.0 avtpsrc ifname=eno1 ! avtpcvfdepay ! avdec_h264 ! video_convert ! autovideosink
```

These are how the packets look in practice, is `gstreamer` capable of handling this or is there something wrong with the `gst` pipeline command as the pipe just gets stuck on `preroll`.

[image: sample packets]